# Running PostgreSQL as sidecar in Kubernetes Pod

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I know there are several professional PostgreSQL Kubernetes Operators out there (crunchy, zalando, kubeDB, stackgres, percona).

But my use case is small and simple.

I thought about running PG in a sidecare together with my application image in a Kubernetes Pod.

All I need is a persistent directory.

It is no problem if the pod gets killed an recreated on a different node, as long as the mounted directory is preserved. I can live with a short downtime in this context.

Of course this means I can only run one pod. Scaling to several pods is not possible, but that's perfectly fine for my small use-case.

Unfortunately there are only articles about scaling PG up, but I found no article how to scale PG down (in the context of Kubernetes).

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: And why do you want to run Postgres as a sidecar specifically, instead of a normal K8s service, like `StatefulSet` or something?

Comment: @mustaccio running a StatefulSet looks more complicated. And having the DB in the same Pod could make the access faster (but I am unsure). And I am curious if this works.

Comment: So, no particular reason then. Fair enough.